# How to scrape the data from multiple sources on single spider call

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running a code to scrape the data from the different website for same product.

For example I have : [www.qrx.com/products](http://www.qrx.com/products) [www.pqr123.com/product](http://www.pqr123.com/product) and [www.abc213.com/product](http://www.abc213.com/product)

category : "tshirt"
Brand: "killler"

As I am trying to call all above sources in single command

```
scrapy crawl loungefly -a category='tshirt' -a brand='killler' -o data.jl
```

but after running all three sources are not working. but when i am commenting 2 of it then 1 is working fine.

```
url_dict = {
            'Backpacks': {
                'Loungefly': {
                    'url':[
                            'https://www.qrx.com/products',
                            'https://www.pqr123.com/product',
                            'https://www.abc213.com/product',
                         ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to scrape the data from all sources?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking at all.  Are you saying you have a spider that parses those urls that isn't working?  Please identify what your problem is.

Comment: I am trying capture a data from three different website sources for same brand and category. for example i want scrape the data for Reebook brand and Shoes category from abc.com xyz.com and pqr.com. I this case scrapy spider it is working for single spider at a time

Comment: so your asking if you can scrape multiple domains at the same time?  the answer is yes you can.